# How to use GetTcpIPv4Statistics

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, tcp, ipv4

I want to get TCP/UDP IPv4 statistics. I serached and I found `GetTcpIPv4Statistics` API. SO, how to use it to get TCP/UDP statistics in a c++ code ?

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: I want to get TCP statistics by using GetTcpIPv4Statistics, the same statistics that provide netstat -s

Comment: So you want to use a .net method in native c++ code, or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That appears to be a .net method only, it calls the underlying [`GetTcpStatisticsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) IP Helper API which is what you want to use from unmanaged C++.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem. To get TCP statistics for IPV4, I used this code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x)) 
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

/* Note: could also use malloc() and free() */

int main()
{
    PMIB_TCPSTATS pTCPStats;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

    pTCPStats = (MIB_TCPSTATS*) MALLOC (sizeof(MIB_TCPSTATS));
    if (pTCPStats == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((dwRetVal = GetTcpStatisticsEx(pTCPStats,AF_INET)) == NO_ERROR) {
      printf("\tActive Opens: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwActiveOpens);
      printf("\tPassive Opens: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwPassiveOpens);
      printf("\tSegments Recv: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwInSegs);
      printf("\tSegments Xmit: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwOutSegs);
      printf("\tTotal # Conxs: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwAttemptFails);
      printf("\tAttemp failed: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwAttemptFails);
      printf("\tcurr estab: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwCurrEstab);
      printf("\testab reset: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwEstabResets);
      printf("\tIn err: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwInErrs);
      printf("\tmax conn: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwMaxConn);
      printf("\tNum conn: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwNumConns);
      printf("\tout rst: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwOutRsts);
      printf("\tretrans seg: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwRetransSegs);
       printf("\tRtoAlgorithm: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwRtoAlgorithm);
        printf("\RtoMax: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwRtoMax);
         printf("\RtoMin: %ld\n", pTCPStats->dwRtoMin);
          printf("\RtoAlgorithm: %ld\n", pTCPStats->RtoAlgorithm);
    }
    else {
      printf("GetTcpStatistics failed with error: %ld\n", dwRetVal);

      LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
      if (FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dwRetVal,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL )) {
        printf("\tError: %s", lpMsgBuf);
      }
      LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );
    }

    if (pTCPStats)
        FREE (pTCPStats);
    system("pause");
}
```

and to get statistics for IPv6, I just replace `AF_INET` by `AF_INET6`

Comment: Honestly though, after careful analysis, the data that is returned is very suspect. I have since used ETW tracing as a more reliable alternative. At some point in the future I will do a tutorial for this.